# How to remove empty elements from an array but with boolean things too

Tags: javascript

See technically meh doing dome project so i need a help where i need to remove `[]`, `null`, `undefined`, `false`

So let the example arr be:

```js
let arr = [null, [], undefined, false, null, 0, 1, 4]
```

So i can remove the undefined false and null by this

```js
arr.filter(Boolean)
```

Problem here is coz `Boolean([])` is true and i want to remove empty arrays too.

So i tried to do something like this

```js
arr.filter(String)
```

Though it filtered elements but not all...

Then i tried some thing like this:

```js
arr.filter(x => x == [] || x) // Keeping the x simply means Boolean(x)
```

Then i noticed something `[] == []` returns `false` where it should come `true` so it will be good if anyone tell me how to do it.

Comment: `arr.filter(x => Array.isArray(x) ? !!x.length : x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ternary operator that checks first if its an array and then checks the length of the array, if its not an array return x

```js
let arr = [null, [],[1,2,3], undefined, false, null, 0, 1, 4]


let filtered = arr.filter(x => Array.isArray(x) ? !!x.length : x)

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a check for the array and length.

```js
let array = [null, [], undefined, false, null, 0, 1, 4, [1]],
    result = array.filter(v => v && (!Array.isArray(v) || v.length));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

And after some answers i have found the answer

```js
arr.filter(x => Array.isArray(x) ? x.length : x == 0 || x)
```

This filters boolean false and [] except 0 and false which i actually needed

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty array first and then for boolean.

```js
let arr = [null, [], undefined, false, null, 0, 1, 4];
let ret = arr.filter((x) =>
  Array.isArray(x) ? x.length > 0 : Boolean(x) === true
);
console.log(ret);
```